# Flutter rebuild parent screen with provider on navigator push

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a license validation system for my application in order to activate it if a license is entered or already present.

If when starting the application the license does not exist then I display a page which allows me to scan it by QR code.

If the scanned license is valid then I push a success page with a button on it that allows me to unlock the application. When I click on this button I want to close my success page and rebuild my application with the homepage of the application unlocked.

This works up to the success page. When I click on my button to unblock the app, I can't rebuild the parent page with the unblock app.

**MyApp: This change choose the screen if I have a license or not.**

```
class AppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Impact',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme().data,
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<LicenseNotifier>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => LicenseNotifier(),
        child: Consumer(
          builder: (context, LicenseNotifier license, _) {
            return license.showScreenWithLicenseState();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**My license notifier:**

```
class LicenseNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  LicenseState state = LicenseState.Uninitialized;
  String getLicenseInApp;
  String licenseScanned;
  String personnalKey;
  final String _scanBarColor = "#f57873";

  LicenseNotifier(){
    personnalKey = "1010";
    _checkIfAppIsUnlocked();
  }

  Future<void> _checkIfAppIsUnlocked() async {
    if (getLicenseInApp != null) {
      state = LicenseState.Authenticated;
    }
    else{
      state = LicenseState.Unauthenticated;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future scanQRCode(BuildContext context) async{
    await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(_scanBarColor, "Cancel", true, ScanMode.QR).then((value) {
      licenseScanned = value.toString();
    });
    licenseValidator(context);
  }

  void licenseValidator(BuildContext context){
    if(licenseScanned == personnalKey){
      showSuccessLicenseScreen(context);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void showSuccessLicenseScreen(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<LicenseNotifier>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => LicenseNotifier(),
          child: LicenseSuccessScreen(title: "Valid license")
      ),
    ));
  }

  activateApp(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    state = LicenseState.Authenticated;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  showScreenWithLicenseState(){
    switch (state) {
      case LicenseState.Uninitialized:
        return SplashScreen();
        break;
      case LicenseState.Unauthenticated:
      case LicenseState.Authenticating:
        return LicenseActivationScreen(title: "Activate license");
        break;
      case LicenseState.Authenticated:
        return ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavigationBarNotifier>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationBarNotifier(),
          child: NavigationBarScreen(),
        );
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**My success screen: When I scan a valid license**

```
class LicenseSuccessScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  final String title;
  const LicenseSuccessScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (() => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.colorContrastGreen,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body : _buildBody(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context)
  {
    var _licenseProvider = Provider.of<LicenseNotifier>(context);

    return Container(
      color: AppColors.colorContrastGreen,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppUi.RATIO * 5),
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ContainerComponent(
            background: AppColors.colorBgLight,
            alignement: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ButtonComponent.primary(
                context: context,
                text: "Débloquer",
                onPressed: () async{
                  _licenseProvider.activateApp(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

So when I click on my button who call "activateApp" in notifier, the success screen closes but I haven't my application content. It just show the LicenseActivationScreen. How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: wdigetin does not detect the action. You have defined your wigdet as StatelessWidget and change it to StatefulWidget. Hover over StatelessWidget to change ctrl +. You can translate by pressing. Seems to be fine with streaming.

Comment: It's possible to pass data on a pushed page with ".then" after "navigator.push". With this I return to the previous page on click to the arrow back button, the previous page is updated. BUT I want update the previous page ONLY when I click on a flat button on the pushed page. How to do that?